# DELETE query results in 'Query Interrupted' MySQL Workbench?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I can successfully delete records manually by click-selecting & deleting row(s) but executing delete queries result in 'Query Interrupted'.

My deletion queries are in the form:

```
DELETE FROM table where column = value;
```

The select statement uses the same values:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column = value;
```

and returns desired results.

What could be causing the delete statement to fail? Are there limits on the amount of records you can delete at once in workbench?

Comment: Several things might cause this. What is the complete error message you are seeing? How many row would be deleted? Do you have an index on the column in the where clause?

Comment: @Sloan it's thousands of records, i did just notice that it also fails when i attempt to delete them all at once, is there a limit to how many records can be deleted at once?  Yes, there's an index.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is a default thousand-row limit in MySQL-Workbench. The SELECT query will return results but DELETE will fail if the number of records to be deleted exceeds one thousand. One option is to limit the results in the query itself or you can adjust the settings as stated in the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-preferences-sql-editor.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to delete the entire contents of a table you can use Truncate.

```
TRUNCATE [TABLE] tbl_name
```

Please see the docs: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/truncate-table.html

Using the DELETE function is usually used for deleting single rows.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-preferences-sql-editor.html#wb-preferences-sql-editor-main), in the **Preferences** >> **SQL Editor** >> **Other**, the **Safe Updates** setting is on by default.

> Safe Updates (rejects UPDATEs and DELETEs with no restrictions)
>
> Enabled by default. Prevents UPDATE and DELETE queries that lack a corresponding key in a WHERE clause, or lack a LIMIT clause, from executing. This option requires a MySQL server reconnection.
>
> When selected, this preference makes it possible to catch UPDATE and DELETE statements with keys that are not used properly and that can probably accidentally change or delete a large number of rows.

I think what this says is that if the setting is on, then the column you are filtering by in the DELETE or UPDATE statement must be the primary key, it cannot be just any column.

If you change the setting to off, then you might need to restart MySQL Workbench for the change to take effect (at least under Linux).